# How to authorize API calls to backend

Tags: api, networking, mobile, https

I am a newbie in the mobile application frontend/backend world. I have a mobile app that has a login screen and services behind the login. After a user logs in, the application sends requests to the appropriate service. The services are sensitive and I don't want anyone just sending requests to the service and getting a response - only people who logged in through the application.

What is the best way to make sure that API calls are originating from a trusted source? I thought of sending the users username and password with every API call in the POST body, but that seems cumbersome so I came here to inquire about a better solution.

Explored sending user credentials in every API call but it would be very cumbersome authenticating every time the user makes an API call.

Explored sending credentials via the body